# Using PHP sessions to send messages to the user

Tags: php, session, message

I have a session class as follows:

```
<?php

class Session {

    function __construct() {
        if (empty(session_id())) {
            session_start();
        }
    }

    function AddMessage($msg="") {
        if (!is_array($_SESSION['messages'])) {
            $_SESSION['messages'] = [];
        }
        array_push($_SESSION['messages'], $msg);
    }

    function GetMessages() {
        $messages = $_SESSION['messages'];
        unset($_SESSION['messages']);
        return $messages;
    }

}

?>
```

Also there is a php file in my layouts directory:

```
<?php if (!empty($_SESSION['messages'])) { ?>
<div class="messages">
<ul>
<?php
    $messages = $session->GetMessages();
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        echo "<li class=\"message\">{$message}</li>";
    }
?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

This piece of code above is included at the top of my pages.
The problem is that in case of single-page submission handling -done in the middle of the page - the messages are printed out before I set it with the AddMessage() method.

Is there a simple way to get around this issue, or I have to rethink my code flow?

Comment: So basically you've started rendering the view before you finished processing the request?

Comment: Then I can only recommend you process your business logic prior to rendering the HTML.  You don't "have to" use an MVC framework if you don't want to, just try not to do everything at once.

Comment: How about using a template engine? E.g smarty

Comment: @user3210615 You can use a template engine sure, personally I'm not a fan of Smarty, I'd probably go with Twig.  But your question was about finding a workaround, or changing your flow.  The first option may fix this one issue, but the later will fix all future issues.  Separating controller from view is changing your code flow.

Comment: Can you explain your solution in short or refer a tutorial, please?

Comment: i am such a peasant..... there was no workaround needed. I just had to place the controller to the top of the page.. probably i have burnt out. sorry for the unnecessary question and thanks for your support anyways